# Selecting dynamically created listboxs items in C#

Tags: c#, winforms

I dynamically created a `Listbox` and filled it with some items, Upon typing a dot in a `Textbox` i want to show the `Listbox` so that the user can select any item by using arrow keys .
I did everything up to this point. When the user types a dot in the `Textbox`, The `Listbox` gets shown, But the arrow keys wont select any items!

```
private void txtResults_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
       string[] words= ((TextBox)sender).Text.Split(' ');
       string s = sampleWord.Text = words[words.Length - 1];

        if (e.KeyCode == Keys.OemPeriod)
        {
            ShowPopUpList(s);
        }
        else if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Down || e.KeyCode == Keys.Up)
        {
            lst.Focus();//doesnt work :-/
        }
        else
        {
            lst.Hide();
            txtResults.Focus();
        }
    }
```

This is the code for creating the listbox on FormLoad()

```
private void CreateListBox()
{

    lst = new ListBox();
    lst.Size = new Size(70, 130);
    lst.RightToLeft = System.Windows.Forms.RightToLeft.Yes;
    lst.KeyDown += lst_KeyDown;                   
    lst.DoubleClick += lst_DoubleClick;    

    //adding some test input
    lst.Items.Add("بسم");
    lst.Items.Add("الله ");
    lst.Items.Add("الرحمن ");
    lst.Items.Add("الرحیم ");
    lst.Items.Add("بنام ");
    lst.Items.Add("خداوند ");
    lst.Items.Add("بخشنده ");
    lst.Items.Add("مهربان ");
    lst.Items.Add("الهی شکرت ");
```

}

```
private void ShowListbox()
{

     txtResults.SelectionStart = txtResults.Text.Length;
     txtResults.SelectionLength = 0;
     Point index = txtResults.GetPositionFromCharIndex(txtResults.SelectionStart-1);
     lst.Location = new Point (index.X-50, index.Y+70);
     this.Controls.Add(lst);
     lst.BringToFront();
     lst.Show();
 }
```

In `ShowPopUpList(s)` the `ShowListbox()` method is called.  nothing fancy about it!

Note:

I only need the list box to get focus when i use UP or DOWN arrow keys to explicitly select an item. unless then i need to be able to freely continue typing and dont lose focus to listbox.
Whats the way around doing it ?

Comment: You should probably show the code you use to create the ListBox.

Comment: i guess you initialize and populate the listbox in ShowPopUpList,if so after all initialization and items added place the focus there and remove it from the textbox keydown handler.

Comment: Also check SelectionMode of the ListBox

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove focus from the textbox keydown handler and place it here:

```
        private void ShowPopUpList(string s)
        {
            //your initialization of the
            //listbox  here and after..
            listBox1.Focus();
        }
```

Another way:

```
if (e.KeyCode == Keys.OemPeriod)
{
     ShowPopUpList(s);
     listBox1.Focus();
}
```

The real big difference is it gets focus rightaway.with your old code would first check the keydown and on the second hit it would already contain the focus.

Final Edit:

If Listbox needs to get the focus on up/down arrow keys(and only with those keys):

```
if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Down || e.KeyCode == Keys.Up)
{
       ShowPopUpList();
       listBox1.Focus();
       listBox1.SelectedIndex = 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks thats it! I wonder why it didnt work inside textbox keydown! whats the difference!?

Comment: the thing is it will work,please checkit with your old code(press the down key not one but 2 times and you will see the selection on the listbox),because it doesent give focus "right-away",i will edit with other solution so the listbox can have the focus right-away(on the first key down),its very simple.

Comment: it is not desireable anymore, when a dot is type i cant continue typing since the focus is transfered to the listbox, and i have to either click or enter to lost the focus and 
start typing again . I only need the list box to get focus when i use UP or DOWN arrow keys to explicitly select an item.
Whats the way around doing it ?

Comment: OK hossein new edit,my first answer was because you told you need the listbox to get focus when user typed a dot and it did,now with the final edit it will recieve focus and select on up/down arrow keys.

Comment: Thanks, didn't solve my problem, I guess its best to ask it in form of another question .

Answer (score 0):

This worked just fine and dandy for me :)

```
    ListBox lb;

    private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (textBox1.Text.Contains("."))
        {
            lb = new ListBox();
            lb.Location = textBox1.Location;
            this.Controls.Add(lb);
            lb.Items.Add("Item 1");
            lb.Items.Add("Item 2");
            lb.Items.Add("Item 3");
            lb.Show();
        }
    }

    private void textBox1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Down)
        {
            lb.Focus();
        }
    }
```