# Can't get focus on dynamically created listbox in C#

Tags: c#, winforms

I have previously asked a question on how to [Selecting dynamically created Listboxs items in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17972211/selecting-dynamically-created-listboxs-items-in-c-sharp) which was answered. The problem now is that when the listbox gets the focus when popped up! I can't continue typing unless I either select an item or press Esc, which I have explicitly defined to set focus back to my `TextBox`.

The irony is that I have a condition in my `KeyDown` event which says if the UP or Down arrow keys are pressed, set the focus on `ListBox` so that user can choose an item, but don't transfer the focus so that user can continue typing freely.

Just like what we have on Visual Studio, when a user presses a dot, he is not blocked and forced to choose an item form the Intellisense list, but he can continue typing and or at any time use arrow keys **UP** or **Down** to select the proper item.

I can't achieve the same functionality using the code below. How can I get this to work as mentioned?

I need to say that using ActiveControl, and transferFocus, using `this.Focus()` prior to `lst.Focus()`, disabling and enabling textbox they all didn't work!

```
private void txtResults_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
   string[] words= ((TextBox)sender).Text.Split(' ');
   string s = sampleWord.Text = words[words.Length - 1];

    if (e.KeyCode == Keys.OemPeriod)
    {
        ShowPopUpList(s);
        lst.Focus();     //This transfers the focus to listbox but then prevents user
                         //from being able to type anymore unless he/she chooses an item!
    }
    else if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Down || e.KeyCode == Keys.Up)
    {
        lst.Focus();//doesnt work :-/
    }
    else
    {
        lst.Hide();
        txtResults.Focus();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want the user to be able to continue typing in the textbox while still manipulating the selection of the listbox, then you will have to fake it: don't actually set focus to the listbox when you show it.  Instead, change the selection of the listbox manually in the `KeyDown` event for the textbox.  Something like this:

```
private void txtResults_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    string[] words = ((TextBox)sender).Text.Split(' ');
    string s = sampleWord.Text = words[words.Length - 1];

    if (e.KeyCode == Keys.OemPeriod)
    {
        ShowPopUpList(s);
        lst.SelectedIndex = 0;
    }
    else if (lst.Visible && e.KeyCode == Keys.Up)
    {
        // manipulate the selection on the listbox (move up)
        if (lst.SelectedIndex > 0) 
            lst.SelectedIndex -= 1;

        // eat the keypress so it textbox doesn't get it and move the cursor
        e.Handled = true; 
    }
    else if (lst.Visible && e.KeyCode == Keys.Down)
    {
        // manipulate the selection on the listbox (move down)
        if (lst.SelectedIndex < lst.Items.Count - 1) 
            lst.SelectedIndex += 1;

        // eat the keypress so it textbox doesn't get it and move the cursor
        e.Handled = true;
    }
    else if (lst.Visible && e.KeyCode == Keys.Enter)
    {
        // insert current list box selection into text box and hide the list
        txtResults.Text += lst.SelectedItem;
        txtResults.SelectionStart = txtResults.Text.Length;
        lst.Hide();
        // eat the keypress to prevent the textbox (and the form) from acting on it
        e.SuppressKeyPress = true;
        e.Handled = true;
    }
    else
    {
        lst.Hide();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, But still i need the listbox to have the focus, since for listbox i have a KeyDown event handled so that when user chooses and item and presses enter, the item is added to the textbox, with this approach that event never gets executed ! So i need a way to get focus

Comment: It is not possible to have focus on two controls at the same time.  That is the point here.  With this approach we are keeping the focus on the textbox, so that keystrokes continue to go into it, but then we *simulate* having focus on the listbox by handling certain keystrokes specially when the listbox is visible.  You can do the same thing for the Enter key; you just need to add another case to the if statement above.  See my edit.

Comment: Thank you verymuch :) Thanks to your help and other folks did as you already told me, I was saved by that suppresskey property:D since i was always getting newline after each enter and didnt know why! good job :)

Answer (score 3):

This behavior is happening because you are shifting focus to the listbox. Try thinking about it differently and instead of giving focus to the listbox, select the next/previous item in the list when the up or down arrows are pressed.

change your "else if" to the following:

```
        else if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Down)
        {
            if (lst.SelectedIndex + 1 < lst.Items.Count)
            {
                lst.SelectedIndex += 1; 
            }
            e.Handled = true;
        }
        else if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Up)
        {
            if (lst.SelectedIndex - 1 >= 0)
            {
                lst.SelectedIndex -= 1;
            }
            e.Handled = true;
        }
```

Comment: Thanks, But still i need the listbox to have the focus, since for listbox i have a KeyDown event handled so that when user chooses and item and presses enter, the item is added to the textbox, with this approach that event never gets executed ! So i need a way to get focus

Comment: actually you can capture the enter key and then take whichever item is currently selected in the listbox and place it in your textbox. A perfect example of how this will behave is the autocomplete for VisualStudio.

if you switch focus to the listbox you are going to lose track of where your cursor is.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to focus your `ListBox` to allow your user to select its item using `Arrow keys`, **your `TextBox` should always be focused**, You have to process the `Enter` right in the `KeyDown` event handler of your `TextBox`, add the selected item there not in the `KeyDown` event handler of your `ListBox`, something like this:

```
private void txtResults_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
  string[] words= ((TextBox)sender).Text.Split(' ');
  string s = sampleWord.Text = words[words.Length - 1];

  if (e.KeyCode == Keys.OemPeriod)
  {
    ShowPopUpList(s);//Show your ListBox without needing to focus it.        
  }

  if(lst.Visible){
    if(e.KeyCode == Keys.Down){      
      lst.SelectedIndex = (lst.SelectedIndex + 1) % lst.Items.Count;
    }
    else if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Up){
      lst.SelectedIndex = lst.SelectedIndex == 0 ? lst.Items.Count - 1 : lst.SelectedIndex - 1
    }
    else if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Enter){//Add the selected Item
        //Add the selected Item here not in the KeyDown event handler of your ListBox
        //.........
        //.........
        //Your TextBox may not need to handle the Enter, so just suppress it after adding the selected item
        e.Handled = true;
    }
    else
    {
      lst.Hide();
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks everything works fine except the textbox which accepts the enter ! it seems e.handled has no effect at all! it just goes to the next line!!

Comment: By the way, doing this , if the listbox gets the focus by being clicked (for example user clicks and item using mouse to add it to the textbox) the textbox focus is lost and thus the Enter key wont be recognized unless i have a KeyDown event defined for listbox to intercept it.! So how can i get around this?

Comment: Thank you very much, Brian Rogers revealed the hidden secret sauce to our problem! the suppresskey! :D 
Thanks again it now works flawlessly ,( i also have the listbox keyDown defined :) )